# async calls not awaited inside foreach

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0

In my c# code, the asynchronous calls from inside the for each are not being awaited everytime.

**CODE**

```
private async Task GetCardInfo()
{
  try
  {
     var result = await DoTask1();
     var info = await DoTask2();
     foreach (var inf in info)
     {
        await DoTask3();
     }
   }
   catch (Exception ex){ }
}
```

`DoTask1();` and `DoTask2();` are always awaited but `DoTask3();` sometimes get awaited sometimes it is not. I thought the issue is with  `DoTask3();` but if I put `DoTask1();` inside foreach loop i am having similar issue. Am i doing something wrong?

The issue only occurs when it is called from inside the foreach loop, if called from outside the foreach loop these functions are awaited as expected.

Can anyone advice?

Comment: Can you provide an [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: does `DoTask3` throw?

Comment: `catch (Exception ex){ }` dont ever do this, and dont put it in a question as it just means we have to ask you more question about the likely possibility that your are throwing away an important exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be either:

1. the info collection is empty (0-length), and  hence the foreach body is not being executed.
2. somebody is throwing an exception (perhaps in DoTask2 or the info enumerator), which is jumping to your catch, and thus skipping the foreach body.

To verify this, run it under the debugger or add some Console.WriteLines().

Comment: In short, excluding the possibility of aliens mysteriously stealing the code, this really is the only 2 options +1

Comment: Or `async void`.

Comment: @StephenCleary oh yes indeed, also it nice to see you visit the halls of SO again